# Bootstrap align elements in nesting columns

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, containers, vertical-alignment

I've looked several times though all the posts I found online as well as here, but none of the methods seem to work.
The question might be a repeat of a common subject but the problem might be specific to this code...

```
<section class="x-graphic">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="images/x1.png" class="x1">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
      <img src="images/x2.png" class="x2">
    </div>

      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="row x-items">
            <div class="imageOne">
              <img src="images/imageOne.png" title="imageOne">&emsp;text&emsp;<p id="imageOne"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="imageTwo">
              <img src="images/imageTwo.png" title="imageTwo">&emsp;text&emsp;<p id="imageTwo"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="imageThree">
              <img src="images/imageThree.png" title="imageThree">&emsp;text&emsp;<p id="imageThree"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="imageFour">
              <img src="images/imageFour.png" title="imageFour">&emsp;text&emsp;<p id="imageFour"></p>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

My CSS is:

```
body {
  padding-top: 90px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
.x1{
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 160px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.x2 {
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

.x-items img {
    height: auto;
    width: 30px;
}

.x-graphic p {
    margin-top: 130px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    display: inline;
}
section p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Problems:

1) Nothing I do centers the `<img>` in the `x-items` row to the **vertical** center. I can center it horizontally, but not vertically.

2) I can't center the elements inside the container horizontally, and i'm only able to do this using a `col-md-offset-x`...

Comment: for point 2, you don't have a row class. And your col-md-'s don't count till 12. Take a look at grids first please. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: The `class` attribute should be used to apply something in common for a group of elements. You should be using `id` in the place of `class = imageTwo` if you are not going to use `imageTwo` anywhere else. 

For point 1, you can either try mentioning `vertical-align:middle` for `imageOne` (**not** for the image, but for the image container). If not, you can try using `line-height` and mentioning height of the image container as the line-height.

Comment: Thanks Hari! using your advice I was able to find 
http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ which helped me use line-height together with vertical-align:middle.

Christophvh, I used row initially and tried playing with it, but it didn't work. The columns don't add to 12 because I didn't want to overload the post with code but it shouldn't matter according to what bootstrap says here when nesting:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting right?

I did go and try row again like you said, and the only way to center is to use col-md-offset-x... is there another way?